# How to get unique value from different rows

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database with rows having actors name in it example

```
row1       row2
movie1     actor1,actor2,actor3
movie2     actor2
movie3     actor1,actor3,actor4,actor6
```

now i want to display a list of actors in one page with no repeat actor in it  ..
is it possible ... output should be

```
actor1
actor2(no repeate)
actor3
actor4
```

here wt was i trying

```
function actors(){
    global $host, $dbname, $user, $pass;
    $DBH = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname", $user, $pass);
    $STH = $DBH->prepare("SELECT DISTINCT actors FROM movies");

    $STH->execute();
    $STH->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    return $STH;
    }

$STH = actors();
     while (($row = $STH->fetch()) !== false) {
     echo $row['actors'].'</br>';
     }
```

but this dont work ... please help
**Edit**
I am getting output

```
actor1,actor2,actor3
actor2
actor1,actor3,actor4,actor6
```

Comment: What do you mean by it doesn't work? Does it break? Does it produce no output? Does it produce the wrong output?

Comment: @andrewsi i have edit the que with my output...

Answer (score 2):

If you are keeping all actor names in a single field, i don't know a simple SQL query which can do this. It's probably not possible or should cost a lot of CPU.

You need to redesign your tables like below.

```
movies
------
id
name

actors
------
id
name

movie_actor_link
----------------
movie_id
actor_id
```

After doing this, it's already very simple to list actors since they have their own table with unique values.

Comment: Akaydin yes that way its very easy but i already have big database ..so is there way we can do it??

Comment: @Harinder I would invest some time getting rid of your database anti-pattern; this is the best time :)

Comment: i think all you need to do is to write a php script to convert tables to new structure. at first, create 3 blank tables like above. then your script should read your current table row by row and insert movie information to movies table, and split actor field from "," character and insert all actors as seperate rows, finally insert movie/actor links to the link table using the created ids. script shouldn't take long and if you make a mistake, it's always easy to truncate the tables and retry. just make sure not to touch the main table. i recommend a backup. :)

Comment: @EmirAkaydın - Anytime the database schema of a system changes, it can mean quite a few changes. While creating the new schema and stuffing the data into it might be simple, don't forget about all the dependent systems that might have to change as a consequence.

Comment: @Thomas: In this case, i still prefer to make the necessery changes for my own application(s). If third party apps need the previous table, i create a view with the same name to support the old table format. That way, at least one of the applications has a proper design and previous ones keep working as well. When it comes to databases, trying to write complex and high CPU cost SQLs to support a wrong design is just not my thing.

Answer (score 1):

What you seek requires that you first split the actor values into rows and then use a DISTINCT query.

This is an example from [Federico Cargnelutti](http://blog.fedecarg.com/2009/02/22/mysql-split-string-function/)

```
CREATE FUNCTION SPLIT_STR(
  x VARCHAR(255),
  delim VARCHAR(12),
  pos INT
)
RETURNS VARCHAR(255)
RETURN REPLACE(SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING_INDEX(x, delim, pos),
       LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(x, delim, pos -1)) + 1),
       delim, '');
```

Then our query might look like:

```
Select Distinct actor
From (
     Select Split_Str( actor, ',', 1 ) As actor From Movies
     Union All Select Split_Str( actor, ',', 2 ) From Movies
     Union All Select Split_Str( actor, ',', 3 ) From Movies
     ...
     Union All Select Split_Str( actor, ',', n ) From Movies
     ) As Z
```

From